# How to trigger "play" in a HTML5 video with hidden controls on IE8 with modernizr

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, modernizr

I managed to play a HTML5 video using video-js on IE8 with help of Modernizr, now the problem is that I want to have the video controls hidden and trigger "play" with a link on the page.
I have a solution that works fine anywhere but ie8 and ie7.

Any ideas please?

```
<html><head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/video.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
 $('.play').click(function(){   $('video').get(0).play(); });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="none" width="640" height="264" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
    <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    <track kind="captions" src="captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" />
</video>

<a href="#" class="play">play</a>

</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue your encoutnering is that your code:

```
$('video').get(0).play();
```

Will only work with the native HTML5 player. Since IE7/8 both don't support the HTML5 `<video>`element, they will both see the Flash fallback provided by *Video.js*.

You should take a look at the [Video.js API](https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/api.md). Instead of your above code, perhaps try:

```
myPlayer = _V_('example_video_1');

$('.play').click(function(){
    myPlayer.play();
});
```